# Django FormWizard dynamic forms

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I am trying to create a FormWizard to add multiple instances of a model at once. The second page is dynamic, based on the number to be added, and creates a single "serial number" field - the differentiating factor between all the instances.

I'm getting the first page of the wizard fine, but the second page - the dynamic one - is giving me this Validation Error:

> [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered.']

All the searching I've done points to a formset issue, which I'm not using. What have I done wrong?

**forms.py**

```
class CarrierWizardForm1(forms.Form):
    part_numbers = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PartNumber.objects.all())
    expiry_date = forms.DateField()
    qty_at_new = forms.IntegerField()
    unit_cost = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, min_value=0, decimal_places=3)
    cost_currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES)

class CarrierWizardForm2(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qty = kwargs.pop('qty')
        super(CarrierWizardForm2,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        for i in qty:
            self.fields['serial_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
```

The defs in CarrierWizardForm2 is a fairly common idiom that is noted all over the web as a solution to this problem, including by [Jacobian](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) Nor is their anything crazy in urls

**urls.py**

```
carrier_wizard_forms = [CarrierWizardForm1, CarrierWizardForm2]
...
url(r'^carrier/add/$', views.CarrierCreateWizard.as_view(carrier_wizard_forms)),
```

My views are relatively complex, but nothing outrageous. Note there are some fields that aren't in the forms - they are filled with context data (user, creation date, etc)

**views.py**

```
TEMPLATES = {"0": "inventory/carrier_wizard_form1.html",
             "1": "inventory/carrier_wizard_form2.html"}

class CarrierCreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    ''' Get the qty from form 1 to indicate how many fields
        form2 needs for serial numbers
    '''
    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        current_step = self.storage.current_step

        if current_step == 'step1':
            prev_data = self.storage.get_step_data('step0')
            return self.initial_dict.get(step, {'qty': qty})

        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        details = form_list[0]
        list_of_serial_nos = form_list[1]

        for serial_name, serial in list_of_serial_nos.cleaned_data.items():
            carrier = Carrier()
            carrier.part_numbers = details.cleaned_data['part_numbers']
            carrier.creation_date = datetime.datetime.today()
            carrier.expiry_date = details.cleaned_data['expiry_date']
            carrier.qty_at_new = 1
            carrier.qty_current = 1
            carrier.serial = serial
            carrier.unit_cost = details.cleaned_data['unit_cost']
            carrier.cost_currency = details.cleaned_data['cost_currency']
            carrier.user = self.request.user

            carrier.save()
```

My second template is bland, although you can see three unsuccessful attempts to rectify this issue.

**inventory/carrier_wizard_form2.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{# Attempt 3 #}
{{ formset }}

{# Attempt 2 {{ form.management_form }}

{% for f in form %}
    {{ f.as_p }}
{% endfor %}

#}
{# Attempt 1 {{ form }} #}

<input type=submit>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**
**As requested, both of my templates**

inventory/carrier_wizard_form1.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ wizard.form.as_p }}
<input type=submit>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

templates/inventory/carrier_wizard_form2.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.form }}

{#
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}..
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}.
{% endif %} #}
</table>
<input type=submit>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is not correct, use `{{ wizard.management_form }}` to add wizard management related stuff and use `{{ wizard.form }}` for forms.

From the [reference doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms) the template is like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ wizard.management_form }} {#add wizard management data #}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}   {# if form is formset #}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}   {#formset's management data #}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}  {#for normal form #}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %} 
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - I've just added the code (arg, straight from the docs and I missed it!), but unfortunately am still getting the same error.

Comment: @datakid, Can you post your *both* updated template?

Comment: added - and of course I saw the problem straight away. Gah. `{{ wizard.management_form }}`

Comment: @datakid, is that resolved? I don't see `{{ wizard.management_form }}` in either of your templates, in 2nd its commented.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I didn't post the corrected template bc I solved it as soon as I re-read my edit. It is now functioning as expected.